# "Of someboy's" vs "of somebody."

Tags: double-possessives

I'm not a native English speaker so I wanted to ask about something that I always hear being said.

> The thing of somebody's.

Is this right? Shouldn't it be this way?

> Somebody's thing.

Or

> The thing of somebody.

Please answer because this is getting me confused.

Comment: Perhaps you might do some research on possessives in English and then come back to  us.

Comment: What is sb supposed to mean?

Comment: @Element I think it is "sb."  for "substantive" because "noun" is no longer a fashionable word in the best linguistic circles, but "substantive" takes too long to write.

Comment: Well isn't my education outdated 

Comment: It's also *somebody.* We often use *sb* as somebody, and also *sth* for something. @Element115

Comment: @Lambie I do know about possessives. I'm telling you that sounds bad to me as well. In fact, I claimed this was "something that I always hear being said".

Comment: You need to provide examples.

Comment: @Lambie "Sweet child of mine" "You wouldn't know him, he's an old friend of mine"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on these two examples:
"Sweet child of mine" "You wouldn't know him, he's an old friend of mine"

One can say the following about these uses of these stand-alone possessive pronouns.

of mine, of theirs, of ours, of yours, of his, of hers, [of its, very unusual].

They are used when the referent (the person who one is referring belongs to a class of persons). It is used to be emphatic, or, in contrast to someone else or something else.

A friend of mine = One of my friends [same thing]

**A friend of mine has that CD**. = **One of my friends has that CD**. Those two sentences mean exactly the same thing.

**This is very different from:**

My friend's CD was not in her living room.

My friend's CD= the CD that belongs to my friend.

"He's an old friend of mine" , therefore, can be expressed as: **He's one of my old friends**. But cannot be expressed as using a noun plus apostrophe s and a noun, as in: my friend's CD.

This is all very standard English.

A friend of his came to the party late. = One of his friends came to the party late.

Comment: I'll take this answer as correct but I do recall hearing things like "some CD of mine" (not specifically this phrase) other nouns that are not people. However, I assume these are colloquial and not actually valid.

Comment: "Some CD of mine was lost in the fire". "One of my CDs was lost in the fire". But: "Iaka's CD was lost in the fire" means something else. Is that clear now? Please try to understand that x of mine equals one of my x's. And that "someone's x" is not the same thing. None of these is colloquial. ***They are all very standard English.***

Comment: oh so now I actually understand what you were trying to explain. +1